# Отмена return false у дочерних элементов

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть блок div, в него вложена ссылка 
На блоке висит функция, которая возращает return false по клику на этот блок.

Как сделать, чтобы ссылка внутри работала по дефолту, то есть осуществлялся переход по этой ссылке.

В данном случае переход по ссылке блокирует функция, которая висит в качестве обработчика на div

```js
$('.wrap').click(function(e) {
  return false;
})
```

```css
.wrap {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <a href="https://www.google.ru/" target="_blank">fwfwefwefwef</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вариант 1. Уберите `return false` у div, зачем он тут? :)

Вариант 2. Поймайте сообщение в дочернем элементе и отмените его распространение наверх:

```
$('.wrap').on('click', 'a', function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Ни один из вариантов не подходит

Comment: @ruslik и почему же? Никто не сможет помочь вам если вы не расскажите о своих затруднениях.

Comment: @ruslik, вот вам вариант "в лоб", но даже оформлять ответом не буду: `$('.wrap a').click(function(){
 location.href = this.href;
});`

Comment: @Deonis вы забыли про target :)

Comment: @PavelMayorov, но тут же всегда `a` будет?

Comment: @PavelMayorov возможно, у автора "накрылся" весь код из-за `proparation`.